# Removing columns in text file with Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a to write a script that remove the Idle column from the output of finger.

```
>finger
Login    Name                 TTY  Idle  Login  Time   Office  Phone
Billy    Billy Howard        *con  6:55  Fri    19:03
Billy    Billy Howard         s00     5  Fri    19:11
Billy    Billy Howard         s00        Sat    00:27
```

I tried remove the extra spaces with tr and then using cut with a delimiter of a space to remove the column, but since Idle can have no value I sometimes get the wrong value since tr delimited the spaces were the idle time should be... Does anyone know how I can remove the Idle column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution is not perfect: the column position and width might change. If they are constant, the following command will do the trick by removing text columns 34 to 39 inclusively:

```
finger | colrm 34 39
```

Comment: All I had to do was find the index of Idle with awk and then use the program. Thanks! fingerOutput=`finger | head -n1`
idleIndex=`awk -v a="$fingerOutput" -v b="Idle" 'BEGIN{print index(a,b)}'`

Answer (score 7):

This might work for you:

```
finger |  sed 's/\(.\{35\}\)...../\1/'
```

or this:

```
finger |  cut --complement -c36-40
```

Answer (score 3):

If `"\t"` is used as column delimiter then you can get rid of 4th column using `awk` and delete doubled `"\t"` using `sed`. For example:

```
finger | awk -F"\t" -v 'OFS=\t' '{ $4=""; print $0}' | sed 's/\t\{2,\}/\t/'
```