# remove single elements in a text file in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed, text-files

Basically what I have is a text file (file.txt), which contains lines of numbers (lines aren't necessarily the same length) e.g.

1 2 3 4 

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12 13

What I need to do is write new files with each of these numbers deleted, one at a time, with replacement e.g. the first new file will contain

2 3 4           <--- 1st element removed

5 6 7 8

9 10 11 12 13

and the 7th file will contain

1 2 3 4

 5 6 8          <--- 7th element removed here

 9 10 11 12 13

To generate these, I'm looping through each line, and then each element in each line. E.g. for the 7th file, where I remove the third element of the second line, I'm trying to do this by reading in the line, removing the appropriate element, then reinserting this new line

$lineNo is 2 (second line)

$line is 5 6 7 8

with cut, I remove the third number, making $newline 5 6 8

Then I try to replace the line $lineNo in file.txt with $newline using sed:

sed -n '$lineNo s/.*/'$newline'/' > file.txt

This is totally not working. I get an error

sed: can't read 25.780000: No such file or directory

(where 25.780000 is a number in my text file. It looks like it's trying to use $newline to read files or something)

I have reason to suspect my way of stating which line to replace isn't working either :(

My question is, a) is there a better way to do this rather than sed, and b) if sed is the way to go, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Comment: Do all the lines have the same number of fields? Is this number known in advance?

Comment: nope :( they might have different lengths

Comment: So if the file contained only contained the line `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11` you would want to create 10 new files, is that correct?

Comment: Hi FJ, 11 new files, because I would remove each once.

Comment: What do you do for the eleventh file with lines with less than 11 numbers? print a blank line?

Comment: Nevermind, I though you were removing the first field from all lines at each iteration.

Comment: Hi Glenn, sorry for the previous bad formatting. If my file had lines with less than 11 numbers, but more than one line, the 11th file would remove the 11th element, so in a file with 10 numbers on the first line, the 11th file would remove the first element on the second line. Thanks..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing columns in text file with Bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238736/removing-columns-in-text-file-with-bash)

Comment: If a line contains the same number twice - do you want to remove both numbers at once (number by value) or stepwise (by position)?

Answer (score 3):

```
filename=file.txt
i=1
while [[ -s $filename ]]; do
    new=file_$i.txt
    awk 'NR==1 {if (NF==1) next; else sub(/^[^ ]+ /, "")} 1' $filename > $new
    ((i++))
    filename=$new
done
```

This leaves a space at the beginning the the first line for each new file, and when a line becomes empty the line is removed. The loop ends when the last generated file is empty.

---

**Update** due to requirement clarification:

```
words=$(wc -w < file.txt)
for ((i=1; i<=words; i++)); do 
    awk -v n=$i '
        words < n && n <= words+NF {$(n-words) = "" }
        {words += NF; print}
    ' file.txt > file_$i.txt
done
```

Comment: Hi Glenn, thanks for the answer. I'm sorry I wasn't clear with what I needed.. I actually need to remove exactly one number from each file, with replacement. So if I had 1 2 3 4 / 5 6 7 8, my second file would have 1 3 4 / 5 6 7 8. I'm going to edit the question to make this more clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstood the question, the following should work, although it will be pretty slow if your files are large:

```
#! /bin/bash

remove_by_value()
{
  local TO_REMOVE=$1

  while read line; do 
    out=
    for word in $line; do [ "$word" = "$TO_REMOVE" ] || out="$out $word"; done
    echo "${out/ }"
  done < $2
}

remove_by_position()
{
  local NTH=$1

  while read line; do
    out=
    for word in $line; do
      ((--NTH == 0)) || out="$out $word"
    done
    echo "${out/ }"
  done < $2
}

FILE=$1
shift  
for number; do
  echo "Removing $number"
  remove_by_position $number "$FILE"
done
```

This will dump all the output to stdout, but it should be trivial to change it so the output for each removed number is redirected (e.g. with `remove_by_position $number $FILE > $FILE.$$ && mv $FILE.$$ $FILE.$number` and proper quoting). Run it as, say,

```
$ bash script.sh file.txt $(seq 11)
```

Comment: You're removing numbers by value, not by position?

Comment: That's how I understood what the OP wanted. I updated the answer to allow for both alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit, that I'm a bit surprised how short the other solutions are.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
file=$1
lines=$(cat $file | wc -l) 
out=0

dropFromLine () {
    file=$1
    row=$2
    to=$((row-1))
    from=$((row+1))
    linecontent=($(sed -n "${row}p" $file))
    # echo "    linecontent: " ${linecontent[@]}
    linelen=${#linecontent[@]}
    # echo "    linelength: " $linelen
    for n in $(seq 0 $linelen) 
    do
        ( 
        if [[ $row > 1 ]] ; then sed -n "1,${to}p" $file ;fi
        for i in $(seq 0 $linelen) 
        do
            if [[ $n != $i ]]
            then
                echo -n ${linecontent[$i]}" " 
            fi
        done
        echo 
        # echo "mod - drop " ${linecontent[$n]}
        sed -n "$from,${lines}p" $file 
        ) > outfile-${out}.txt
        out=$((out+1))
    done 
}

for row in $(seq 1 $lines)
do 
    dropFromLine $file $row 
done
```

invocation:

```
./dropFromRow.sh num.dat
```

num.dat:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11
```

result:

```
outfile-0  outfile-10  outfile-12  outfile-2  outfile-4  outfile-6  outfile-8
outfile-1  outfile-11  outfile-13  outfile-3  outfile-5  outfile-7  outfile-9
```

samples:

```
asux:~/proj/mini/forum > cat outfile-0
2 3 4  
5 6 7 8
9 10 11
asux:~/proj/mini/forum > cat outfile-1
1 3 4  
5 6 7 8
9 10 11
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `file.txt`:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12 13
```

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Read all input to a scalar variable as a single string.
my $str;
{
        local $/ = undef;
        $str = <>;
}

## Loop for each number found.
while ( $str =~ m/(\d+)(?:\h*)?/g ) {

        ## Open file for writing. The name of the file will be
        ## the number matched in previous regexp.
        open my $fh, q[>], ($1 . q[.txt]) or
                die qq[Couldn't create file $1.txt\n];

        ## Print everything prior to matched string plus everything
        ## after matched string.
        printf $fh qq[%s%s], $`, $';

        ## Close file.
        close $fh;
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl file.txt
```

Show files created:

```
ls [0-9]*.txt
```

With output:

```
10.txt  11.txt  12.txt  13.txt  1.txt  2.txt  3.txt  4.txt  5.txt  6.txt  7.txt  8.txt  9.txt
```

Show content of one of them:

```
cat 9.txt
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
10 11 12 13
```